# Http Flood vs Nginx. How can I check if $http_referer has more than 2 digit?

Tags: nginx, ddos

Some logs

```
46.196.164.146 - - [21/Feb/2015:20:05:45 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10930 "http://22on8mj7w7wpcc.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0" "-"
78.171.167.204 - - [21/Feb/2015:20:05:45 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10931 "http://y707yvc8a.net/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; U; Edition Romania Local; ru) Presto/2.10.289 Version/8.09" "-"
78.171.167.204 - - [21/Feb/2015:20:05:45 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10930 "http://87rk11k0.ua/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0" "-"
78.174.146.52 - - [21/Feb/2015:20:05:45 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10931 "http://8811mm213kc34.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" "-"
176.43.210.33 - - [21/Feb/2015:20:05:45 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10930 "http://qh0lx1wqp17.ru/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0" "-"
```

User agent change randomly. Is there any way to do in nginx conf

```
if (preg_match('/\d{3}/', $invalid_referer)) {
    return 403;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just make a rewrite rule at this case:

```
if ($http_referer ~* ".*[0-9]{2}.*") {
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: how to check if referer consist of 2 or more digit? 
for example 2sdf3.com - false, 2s2df3.com - true, 2lj42nj43.com - true

Comment: make a regex you need. For example, for having at least 2 digits:
.*[0-9].*[0-9].*
but why is: 2sdf3.com - false? it still has two digits.